# Changing location of html element dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the pixel location of an html element using JavaScript. My function should take in a user input for the location and change the pixel coordinates according to an array.

This function should create a button at the user inputted location, but nothing happens. I think the issue is with setting a style attribute that requires both a text string and the variable that stores the location string. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var arr = [
  ["A1", "left:81px;"],
  ["A2", "left:145px;"]
]

function moveObject(arr) {
  var location = prompt("Enter location", "A1");
  var i;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i][0] === location) {
      destination = arr[i][1] + ";";
    }
  }
  var box = document.createElement("button");
  box.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;");
  box.setAttribute("style", destination)
  box.innerText = location; 
  document.body.appendChild(box);
}
moveObject(arr)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and deleted a stray `"` and added `box.innerText = location; `

Comment: Why are you adding `;` to something that already has a `;` - either remove it from the array or from `destination = arr[i][1] + ";";`

Comment: See my answer for a simpler version

Comment: Note that you can also just do `box.style += "position: absolute;"; box.style += destination;` You might also look into `box.textContent` rather than `innerText`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey for some reason, I don't seem to be able to use innerHTML, innerText, or textContent. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 at a DE so maybe some things aren't available to me.

Comment: What does it mean when you say you can't use those properties? Do you get an error or something? Just because something doesn't come up in IntelliSense doesn't mean it doesn't exist :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes I get an error saying it's an invalid argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the css value strings and only call `setAtrribute('style')` once.

The second call wipes out the first

You are also adding an extra `;` when it already exists in the value in your array.

Note I have not added any validation that the user entered value exists in the array. You will need to do that yourself before adding `undefined` values in the style

```js
var arr = [
  ["A1", "left:81px;"],
  ["A2", "left:145px;"]
]

function moveObject(arr) {
  var location = prompt("Enter location", "A1");
  var i;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i][0] === location) {
      destination = arr[i][1] ;
    }
  }
  var box = document.createElement("button");
  // combine style values
  box.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;" + destination);
 
  box.innerText = location; 
  document.body.appendChild(box);
}
moveObject(arr)
```

Comment: I took out the ";" when defining the destination variable, and I changed it to box.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;"+destination); but it didn't work. box.innerText does not seem to be a valid attribute I can use.

Comment: Works fine only if one of those two values in your array is entered in prompt.... that's where you also need validation of the user input

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

I removed a stray `"` and added some text. Then I moved the left from the string and used the location as a lookup table instead

```js
var arr = {
  "A1":  {"left":"81px"},
  "A2":  {"left":"145px"}
}

function moveObject(arr) {
  var location = prompt("Enter location", "A1");
  if (arr[location]) {
    var box = document.createElement("button");
    box.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;");
    var key = Object.keys(arr[location])
    box.style[key] = arr[location][key]
    box.innerText = location; 
    document.body.appendChild(box);
  }
  else alert("Location '"+location+"' not available")
}
moveObject(arr)
```